# Testing PocketSphinx server

Tags: ruby

I'm interested in setting up a web based speech recognition service for testing purposes. I did some research and found Ruby PocketSphinx Server. They claim to accept input as an audio file and return a JSON file with the text from the audio input. This is exactly what I need.

The problem is I'm new to Ruby and Sphinx/PocketSphinx. Even though I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/alumae/ruby-pocketsphinx-server/blob/master/README.rdoc) to setup the environment, I'm still completely lost. I got as far as running this command `unicorn -c unicorn.conf.rb config.ru` but got this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/unicorn/configurator.rb:74:in `read': No
such file or directory - unicorn.conf.rb (Errno::ENOENT)    from
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/unicorn/configurator.rb:74:in `reload'    from
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/unicorn/configurator.rb:67:in `initialize'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/unicorn/http_server.rb:104:in `new'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/unicorn/http_server.rb:104:in
`initialize'    from /usr/bin/unicorn:121:in `new'  from
/usr/bin/unicorn:121:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the root directory of the ruby-pocketsphinx-server folder there should be a file called unicorn.conf.rb.

You should be running the unicorn -c unicorn.conf.rb config.ru command in the root directory.